# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' Django

Tags: django

I'm getting this error when I try to log in with a nonvalid user, I want to be redirected to the login page instead.

It highlights the user.save() on muy views.py

**views.py**

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(request, **form.cleaned_data)
            user.save()
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('login'))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'accountApp/login.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

**login.html**

```
{% block content %}

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <h1>Login</h1>
    <fieldset class="form-group" style="width: 250px;">
      {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

authenticate function returns None in case credentials are wrong so check if user is valid or not. change if condition to `if user is not None:`
i.e. views.py looks like this.

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(request, **form.cleaned_data)
            # user variable will be None if it is an invalid user
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('login'))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'accountApp/login.html', {'form': form})
```

refer docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login